# How to publish custom pages from feature

Tags: publishing-page, auto-approve

I have created a custom Home page as well as another custom page which are being added to the pages library in a publishing portal site. The pages are successfully being added, however they are not published, they are in pending status. I would like to have them both published once the feature is activated, how can i go about doing this?

Other info:
The pages are being added via a module.Is there a way i can find the pages and activate in an event receiver? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try something like:

```
SPList lstPages = web.Lists.TryGetList("Pages");
if (lstPages != null)
{
    SPListItemCollection pagesColl = lstPages.Items;
    foreach (SPListItem page in pagesColl)
    {
        page.File.Publish("Page published by Feature Event Receiver");
    }
}
```

If you want to get only those pages which you have created, you can use [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx) to filter List Items or in the loop you can put condition like `if (page["Title"] == "Your Page Title")`

Let me know if you need help